# Using xargs with mv and mkdir command in Linux

Tags: linux, xargs

I am attempting to create a directory using the command `mkdir`. However, I would like to move a subset of files into that directory. I understand I can use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), however my attempts have failed. For example, I have tried `mkdir test | xargs -i mv test.text {}`. It creates the directory, but it does not move the file `test.txt` into it after it has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir` does not output anything, therefore `xargs` will not do anything useful. I don't understand exactly what you want to do, so you should explain your question better.

"would like to move a subset of files into that directory" -> do files in this subset share one or more traits? If yes, use the [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) command like this:

```
find [conditions] -exec mv "{}" dirname \;
```

If you want to avoid typing the name of the directory twice, or if you are doing this from a script, you can do something like

```
dirname=test
mkdir $dirname && mv filename $dirname
```

Comment: @user49740- Thanks. I wasn't aware that `mkdir` wasn't producing any output. I thought it did as it displays them in standard output i.e. the monitor. The files don't share a specific trait. I am simply attempting to create a directory and then to move files that I need to have moved into the newly created directory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mkdir produces any output to pipe to xargs.

Doing "mkdir test1 test2 testhello3 | grep hello" doesn't produce any output while doing "ls | grep hello" will show me "testhello3".

Can you produce the folders first and then use ls then grep and then xargs to do it?

```
ls | grep (unique search to get folder name) | xargs -i mv test.txt {}
```

Maybe more information on criteria of moving files and such would be helpful.

Comment: There is a specific criteria to move the files. It is simply to create a directory and then to move specific files to that directory.

Comment: Well I mean if you're making it at the moment and then moving files then you can just do "mkdir foldername && mv file.txt file2.txt file3.txt foldername/." Since you know the foldername and files.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, close to user49740's answer:

```
mkdir test && find -type f -name 'test.*' -exec mv {} test \;
```

how many diferent directories do you want to create?

Comment: Sorry am new to the world of `find` commands in the terminal but what does `\` do at the end of the command?

Comment: If you meant the backslash, it stops the semicolon from being interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Of if you mean `'test.*'`, the `''` prevent the shell from expanding the `*` and leave it as it is for `find`.